# C++ Link Error Missing GetTickCount And How To Debug

Tags: c++, debugging, linker

I have been refactoring some header includes, and all of sudden I am left with this (changed some namespaces and class names) link error:

```
Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class ABC::DEF::JKL __thiscall ABC::GHI::GetTickCount(void)const " (?GetTickCount@GHI@ABC@@QBE?AVJKL@DEF@2@XZ) Server.obj
```

The thing is, there is not a single reference to GetTickCount in my code. I did a few clean rebuilds, to no avail.

What would be the next step to debug this? Is there any chance of finding out the offending line? From above message it looks as if the offending item is in the Server compilation unit, is it possible to narrow it down further? Why would I even get an unresolved external symbol that I never referenced?

Thanks

Comment: Something that is being called from the file creating `server.obj` is linking in a class `ABC::DEF::JKL` that has a function `GetTickCount()` that is being called.  This does not necessarily mean it is one of your classes, especially if you are using any 3rd party libraries.  Can you post the exact error, and/or more code?

Comment: That is the exact error, and ABC::DEF::JKL is my class, and most certainly has no GetTickCount() function. External libraries are limited to boost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, winbase.h is so nice as to

```
#define GetCurrentTime() GetTickCount()
```

Comment: Yeah, Windows headers are annoying like that. Worst abuse of macros ever.

Comment: @Cookie: So what was the solution?  Did you have to rename your `GetCurrentTime()` function?

Comment: @User: yes indeed, I just ended up renaming it. Alternatively I could have just undefined windows' definition though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is release build of your code. Rebuild it in debug mode and linker should tell you exact line number of unresolved external in `Server.obj`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're building on Windows, as [GetTickCount() is a function provided from Kernel32 library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You need to add Kernel32.lib into your linker library line.  I usually do this from QMake with the line:

```
LIBS *= Kernel32.lib
```